# Where's a good place for Application-wide settings in ASP.NET 3.5?

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET Web Site/Application, and was wondering where a good place to put some application wide settings would be. If feasible, I'd like to avoid rolling my own solution, and use what's already there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put them inside the web.config file

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MySetting" value="Value" />
  </appSettings>
```

and access them using ConfigurationManager.

```
var value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySetting"];
```

Note you will have to add a reference to `System.Configuration` and add a using statement (assuming c#);

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably in the web.config file. You can create an `AppSettings` element that can contain custom settings. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154.aspx for more details.

You would then retrieve these using:

```
NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your configuration is more complex than simple key/value pairs, i prefer to use my own [configuration sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the kind of settings you want to store.
Most of the situations are handled well using web.config file (which is located on the root of your web application folder).
A common use of it is to store connection strings to databases or a folder path.

Although you can edit it manually (it's an xml file) I advice you use the integrated UI that ASP.NET has. In Solution Explorer select your web project, on the top of the frame you'll see a globe with a red hammer icon. This will launch ASP.NET Configuration which let's you edit your settings stored in web.config